# Stop reading after a certain character

Tags: c#

is there a way to make the code stop reading after it read the first " mark?

```
Games input is ["gameextrainfo":"Potion Craft: Alchemist Simulator","gameid":"1210320","]
```

```
using System;
public class CPHInline
{
    public bool Execute()
    {
                String str = args["Games"].ToString();
        string result = str.Substring(17);
        CPH.SendMessage(result, true);
        return true;
  }
}
```

I want it to output this msg
`The Game is [Name of the game]` in this case it would be Potion Craft: Alchemist Simulator and then stop with out printing the " mark after it

I've used this way

```
using System;

public class CPHInline
{
    public bool Execute()
    {
        
        String str = args["Games"].ToString();
   String result = str.Contains("\"") ?  str.Substring(17, str.IndexOf("\"")): str;
   CPH.SendMessage(result, true);
   return true;
        
        return true;
    }
}
```

but it only print the first letter of the game name then stops I don't know why and how.

Comment: You can use [String.IndexOf](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.indexof) to determine the position of the character `"` and [String.Substring](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.substring) to get only the desired part.

Comment: That fragment looks like it could be JSON. So maybe use Json deserialisation

Answer (score 0):

You can use IndexOf to find the index of a specific character or string and then use Substring with both startindex and length. You might want to check if it actually contains a " before using subsrting

```
public bool Execute()
{
   String str = args["Games"].ToString();
   var result = str.Contains("\"") ? str.Substring(0, str.IndexOf('\"')): str;
   CPH.SendMessage(result, true);
   return true;
}
```

**Update**

After updating the question, given this input string:

```
["gameextrainfo":"Potion Craft: Alchemist Simulator","gameid":"1210320","]
```

You are looking for the text between the third and the forth quote mark. Then I'd rather go for the split approach in Melliks answer. If there are less than 4 quote marks this will return the text after the last quote mark.

```
public bool Execute()
{
   String str = args["Games"].ToString();
   var splits = str.Split('\"');
   var result = splits.Length > 3 ? splits[3] : splits[splits.Length - 1];
   CPH.SendMessage(result, true);
   return true;
}
```

result will be

```
Potion Craft: Alchemist Simulator
```

Comment: it worked but for some reason it only print the first letter of the name and stops

Comment: `str.Substring(0, str.IndexOf('\"'))` should be `str.Substring(str.IndexOf('\"'))` - OP wants a string AFTER the `"` and not BEFORE

Comment: That's because your string apparently starts with a ", but that's not what you have shown in the question. The answer here works for `Safehouse","gameid":"2271300"` but not for ."Safehouse","gameid":"2271300"`.

Comment: @YazeedNawaf It's a bit unclear exactly what you are after, can you edit the question to include the exact input string and what you expect as output. Does it actually start with Safehouse" or is it an additionaly " in the beginning? Are you expecting the word Safehouse as output, or something else?

Comment: @Johan I edited it and added some info and the required output

Comment: @YazeedNawaf Okey, it looks a bit like json but it's not a valid/complete json. I updated the answer

Answer (score -1):

You can use

```
string result = str.Split("\"")[0]
```

and just enter the character you want into the Split function. In this case with a Backslash because you need to escape the **"** character.

You need a check such as

```
if (str.contains("\"")) {
```

in order to prevent an IndexOutOfBoundsException as stated in the comments.

Additionally if you want everything after the first instance of the character but before the second you change it to

```
string result = str.Split("\"")[1]
```

or if you want to get something in-between some character and a second character you do

```
string result = str.Split("\"")[1].Split("a")[0]
```

Again, in each of these cases you can replace the **\"** with any character. Example:

```
string result = str.Split("a")[0]
```

Comment: What will happen if there is no `"` character present? Accessing an index blindly like you propose with `str.Split("\"")[1]` is a very bad idea.

Comment: Maybe you should try for yourself. `str.Split("\"")[1]` does throw IndexOutOfBoundsException if no " present.

Comment: I agree and admit I was wrong.
I have added a recommended check to the relevant functions.

Comment: @Mellik First of all I am glad that you finally understood what I meant. I did not have to check for myself as I already knew that trying to access an index of an array which is out of bounds will throw a corresponding exception. I was merely giving you a hint that your answer does not take into consideration that data might not always be the way it is expected to be.

Comment: @Mellik Secondly I find it very strange that you would simply downvote my latest answers just because you did not understand the topic (or at least did not think it through) you were trying to provide an answer for. That clearly tells everything about your mindset. As a result the downvote stays as a reminder to accept hints and think about your solution instead of getting into some sort of rage.

Comment: Fair enough. I have attempted to remove the downvotes but they are locked in place. I will accept this incident as a lesson. I wish you a nice day